# JAVAPNS setAllowYouTube,setAllowCamera issue

Tags: ios, mdm

Hi i am using JavaPNS for IOS MobileDeviceManagament . Steps followed up to now
1)I installed mobileconfig file on iPad .
2)I setup JavaPNS project on Windows system.
3)I can able to send alerts,sounds and badges using Push.alert(...),Push.Sound(...),Push.Badge()
4)My intention is disabling the camera.The following code is used for it.

RestrictionsPayload rsp= new RestrictionsPayload(1, "raja", "com25.restrictions", "allowYouTube") ;
The above class provides some features like enabling camera,youtube..etc. So i am using this class.
 rsp.setAllowCamera(false);
 rsp.setAllowYouTube(false);
I am adding this methods to the rsp object.
Push.payload(rsp,"PushNotification.p12", "aadmin123(", false, "36........6");

Using above statement i am sending rsp object to the IOS device .

Here RestrictionsPayload class is using for enabling camera and youtube .The two methods are using for enabling camera and youtube. The server log is not showing any error.

Can any one guide me.

Comment: Please add more details on what's wrong. Was you able to install a profile? If no, have you checked device console? Have you seen any issues on returned by you code?

Comment: Hi victor thank you . I installed mobileconfig file on IOS device. I can able to send alerts,sounds and badges also. When i am using setcamera(false) method ,it is not performing  operation. In server log it is not showing any kind of error. Steps i followed up to now.1)I installed IOS application on iPad.2)I installed mobileconfig file.3)I set up JavaPNS project in my windows System 4)I send alerts,sounds and badges using push.alert(.....); push.sound(...);,push.badge(..);,  .5)Similary i am using RestrictionsPayload as i above written the code. 6)The server is not showing any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two important notes:

a) You can **push** by default only sounds, bages and alerts. You can't push configuration profiles if you don't have MDM.

b) To install configuration profile on your device over the air you have to do one of two things
 - Point browser to your configuration profile and manually accept it
 - Install MDM profile first which will allow you to push new configuration profiles to the device.

Based on your description, you are missing MDM profile. Did you install it and configured properly?

Comment: Hi Victor thank you for you response. I am using iPhone Configuration Utility for generating mobileconfig file. According to your note (b) i understand that first i need to set up MDM server. Inorder to perform Restrictions payload i need to setup MDM Server. But in iPhone Configuration Utility Restrictions Payload is separately generating. For performing Restrictions Payload i need to  setup MDM profile right. So please guide me if am wrong

Comment: Hi victor please give me answers to my question.1)How can i update mobileconfig file On IOS device. 2)How can i read notifications at client side pro grammatically,is it possible? 3)Using JavaPNS payloads can i manage things like camera,youtube,wifi (Enable/disable).If so can i implement code on client side(IOS application). 4)I am following below document regarding plist management please click on below link http://intrepidusgroup.com/insight/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2011/08/InsideAppleMDM.pdf
They are telling that i need to implement client side code for updating plist.

Comment: 1) You need to enroll device in MDM first and you need to send InstallConfiguration command along with profile (generally speaking it goes absolutely different way than badges and sounds) 2) Please write it as separate question 3) I don't know 4) I didn't read this document (I read official Apple MDM document). For MDM you don't need to implement anything on the client side.

Comment: Hi victor thank you for answers. I am implementing MDM and i will integrate it.